# Terraform: Iterate over keys in JSON file

Tags: json, foreach, terraform

Using Terraform I need to loop over some JSON and create some files.

This is the file I'm reading in:

```
{
    "files": {
      "file1": {
        "a": {
          "unusedValue": "val"
        }
      },
      "file2": {
        "a": {
          "unusedValue": "val"
        },
        "b": {
          "unusedValue": "val"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I can't change the format of this file, I need to use to create 3 files:

- file1a
- file2a
- file2b

At the minute, I've got this:

```
locals {
    json = jsondecode(file("files.json"))

    files = flatten([ for v in local.json.files: 
      [ for file, fileLetter in v:
        { "file" = file,
          "fileLetter" = fileLetter}
      ]
     ])

}

# resource local_file file {
#   for_each = { for idx, v in local.files: idx => v }
#    content  = "Temp content"
#    filename = "${path.module}/${each.value.file}-${each.value.fileLetter}"
#}

output myout {
    value = local.files
}
```

But it's giving the wrong output - it's taking the contents of the second object rather than it's name and the first bit isn't using the fileA, fileB, etc.

```
    [
      + {
          + file       = "a"
          + fileLetter = {
              + unusedValue = "val"
            }
        },
      + {
          + file       = "a"
          + fileLetter = {
              + unusedValue = "val"
            }
        },
      + {
          + file       = "b"
          + fileLetter = {
              + unusedValue = "val"
            }
        },
    ]
```

It should be:

```
    [
      + {
          + file       = "file1"
          + fileLetter = "a"
        },
      + {
          + file       = "file2",
          + fileLetter = "a"
        },
      + {
          + file       = "file2",
          + fileLetter = "b"
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
files = flatten([ for file, fileObject in local.json.files: 
      [ for fileLetter, _ in fileObject:
        { "file" = file,
          "fileLetter" = fileLetter}
      ]
     ])
```

With the original `for v in local.json.files`, you're iterating over only the inner objects, e.g.

```json
{
  "a": {
    "unusedValue": "val"
  }
}
```

Instead, you want to read both the key and the value from the JSON object in `files`. This can be done by [using two temporary variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#input-types), `file, fileObject`. This is the same syntax you originally used in your `file, fileLetter`.